# Installation of memcached - unable to find libevent

Tags: unix, memcached, libevent

To install memcached I run:

```
./configure
```

from memcached server location but I receive error:

```
checking for libevent directory... configure: error: libevent is required.  You can get it from http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/

      If it's already installed, specify its path using --with-libevent=/dir/
```

So I installed libevent manually by downloading from http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/ and running ./configure from downloaded libevent folder

But when I try command:

```
./configure  --with-libevent=/export/home/me/libevent-2.0.21-stable/
```

I receive same error :

```
checking for libevent directory... configure: error: libevent is required.  You can get it from http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/

      If it's already installed, specify its path using --with-libevent=/dir/
```

How can I check where libevent is installed? Am I specifying the path correctly?

I'm required to install libevent manually as I'm installing memcached from behind a firewall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After downloading and extracting `libevent`, you have to configure, build and install it.

Only then can you go back to the `memcached` directory and rerun its configure, specifying where you installed `libevent` if it wasn't in one of the standard places (such as `/lib`, `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`).

Comment: Complementary note: the commands to configure, build and install `libevent` can be found at its [github page](https://github.com/libevent/libevent#autoconf)